# Algorithm to divide text into 3 evenly-sized groups

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm would like to create an algorithm that will divide text into 3-evenly sized groups (based on text length).  Since this will be put to use for line-breaks, the order of the text needs to be maintained.

For instance this string:

```
Just testing to see how this works.
```

would sort to:

```
Just testing   // 12 characters
to see how     // 10 characters
this works.    // 11 characters
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_wrap

Comment: Bonus points if you can make it for n-groups instead of just 3!  ;)

Comment: So, do you need to sort text or split it? It's kinda different things.

Comment: It should be n groups of relatively similar size ? Please explain what decides the size of the groups.

Comment: Forget the n-groups.  Just 3 groups that are as close in size as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "minimum raggedness" dynamic program, also from the Wikipedia article on word wrap, can be adapted to your needs. Set `LineWidth = len(text)/n - 1` and ignore the comment about infinite penalties for exceeding the line width; use the definition of `c(i, j)` as is with `P = 2`.

---

```
Code. I took the liberty of modifying the DP always to return exactly n lines, at the cost of increasing the running time from O(#words ** 2) to O(#words ** 2 * n).

def minragged(text, n=3):
    """
    >>> minragged('Just testing to see how this works.')
    ['Just testing', 'to see how', 'this works.']
    >>> minragged('Just testing to see how this works.', 10)
    ['', '', 'Just', 'testing', 'to', 'see', 'how', 'this', 'works.', '']
    """
    words = text.split()
    cumwordwidth = [0]
    # cumwordwidth[-1] is the last element
    for word in words:
        cumwordwidth.append(cumwordwidth[-1] + len(word))
    totalwidth = cumwordwidth[-1] + len(words) - 1  # len(words) - 1 spaces
    linewidth = float(totalwidth - (n - 1)) / float(n)  # n - 1 line breaks
    def cost(i, j):
        """
        cost of a line words[i], ..., words[j - 1] (words[i:j])
        """
        actuallinewidth = max(j - i - 1, 0) + (cumwordwidth[j] - cumwordwidth[i])
        return (linewidth - float(actuallinewidth)) ** 2
    # best[l][k][0] is the min total cost for words 0, ..., k - 1 on l lines
    # best[l][k][1] is a minimizing index for the start of the last line
    best = [[(0.0, None)] + [(float('inf'), None)] * len(words)]
    # xrange(upper) is the interval 0, 1, ..., upper - 1
    for l in xrange(1, n + 1):
        best.append([])
        for j in xrange(len(words) + 1):
            best[l].append(min((best[l - 1][k][0] + cost(k, j), k) for k in xrange(j + 1)))
    lines = []
    b = len(words)
    # xrange(upper, 0, -1) is the interval upper, upper - 1, ..., 1
    for l in xrange(n, 0, -1):
        a = best[l][b][1]
        lines.append(' '.join(words[a:b]))
        b = a
    lines.reverse()
    return lines

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: I read about the minimum raggedness and it does seem to be exactly what I need.  I have no idea how to convert that equation to usable code though.  Any ideas?

Comment: Ugh... I'm trying to go through it and convert it to Objective-C and Actionscript... but I'm failing on both accounts.  Is that a python script?  I hate to be so co-dependent, but I just can't parse it...even with the code hints.

Comment: Well, that is definitely what I'm looking for!  Thanks a million.  I'm gonna see if I can find a friend who knows Python.

Comment: This code was written in Objective-C and placed here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075203/converting-a-python-script-to-objective-c)

Comment: I adopted the code for Swift and placed it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059956/algorithm-to-divide-text-into-3-evenly-sized-groups?nah=1#28822505

Answer (score 1):

You can try the next simple heuristic for starters: Place to iterators in n/3 and 2n/3 and search for the closest space near each of them.

Comment: Can you create some code for this?  I don't understand what you mean.  :(

Answer (score 0):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_wrap:

```
SpaceLeft := LineWidth
for each Word in Text
    if Width(Word) > SpaceLeft
        insert line break before Word in Text
        SpaceLeft := LineWidth - Width(Word)
    else
        SpaceLeft := SpaceLeft - (Width(Word) + SpaceWidth)
```

> This method is used by many modern word processors, such as OpenOffice.org Writer and Microsoft Word. This algorithm is optimal in that it always puts the text on the minimum number of lines.

Comment: I think the question is different from usual word wrapping.  Usually, you know the line width in advance, and the algorithm determines the number of lines.  Here, you know the number of lines in advance, and the algorithm determines the line width.

Comment: How about taking the length of the string and divide it by the number of lines you want? It would give an approximation at least.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from "someone" works fine. However, I had problems translating this into SWIFT code. Here is my translation for all those that are interested.

```
import Foundation   

class SplitText{
    typealias MinRag = (Float, Int) // meaning (cost for line (so far), word index)

    // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426017/word-wrap-to-x-lines-instead-of-maximum-width-least-raggedness?lq=1
    class func splitText(text:String, numberOfLines:Int)-> [String]{
        //preparations
        var words = split(text, maxSplit:100, allowEmptySlices: false, isSeparator:{(s:Character)-> Bool in return s == " " || s == "\n"})
        var cumwordwidth =  [Int](); //cummulative word widths
        cumwordwidth.append(0);
        for word in words{
            cumwordwidth.append(cumwordwidth[cumwordwidth.count - 1] + count(word));
        }
        var totalwidth = cumwordwidth[cumwordwidth.count - 1] + count(words) - 1;
        var linewidth:Float = Float(totalwidth - (numberOfLines - 1)) / Float(numberOfLines)

        // cost function for one line for words i .. j
        var cost = { (i:Int,j:Int)-> Float in
            var actuallinewidth = max(j - i - 1, 0) + (cumwordwidth[j] - cumwordwidth[i]);
            var remainingWidth: Float = linewidth - Float(actuallinewidth)
            return remainingWidth * remainingWidth
        }

        var best = [[MinRag]]()
        var tmp = [MinRag]();
        //ensure that data structure is initialised in a way that we start with adding the first word
        tmp.append((0, -1));
        for  word in words {
            tmp.append((Float.infinity , -1));
        }
        best.append(tmp);
        //now we can start. We simply calculate the cost for all possible lines
        for l in 1...numberOfLines {
            tmp = [MinRag]()
            for j in 0...words.count {
                var min:MinRag = (best[l - 1][0].0 + cost(0, j), 0);
                var k: Int
                for k = 0; k < j + 1 ; ++k  {
                    var loc:Float = best[l - 1][k].0 + cost(k, j);
                    if (loc < min.0 || (loc == min.0 && k < min.1)) {
                        min=(loc, k);
                    }
                    println("l=\(l), j=\(j), k=\(k), min=\(min)")
                }
                tmp.append(min);
            }
            best.append(tmp);
        }

        //now build the answer based on above calculations
        var lines = [String]();
        var b = words.count;
        var o:Int
        for o = numberOfLines; o > 0 ; --o {
            var a = best[o][b].1;
            lines.append(" ".join(words[a...b-1]));
            b = a;
        }
        return reverse(lines);
    }
}
```